# Syncing URL with instantsearch using next.js adding one unnecessary re-route

Tags: next.js, algolia, instantsearch.js, react-instantsearch, instantsearch

I am using next.js and currently I have an input on my homepage that allows a user to enter a search. I made it so that when a user submits their search on the homepage, it takes me to the /search page which uses algolia's instantsearch with the search already applied (to do this, I used routing={true} on my InstantSearch component).

The issue I have comes from the browser history. So when a user types "phone" on the home-page, it goes from "/" -> "/search?search=phone" -> "/search?<index_name>%5Bquery%5D=phone". Now when the user clicks the back button on the browser, it takes them to "/search?search=phone" which isn't actually connected to algolia, so it just shows the /search page with all the results in my index. How can I have it so that the user is instantly taken to "/search?<index_name>%5Bquery%5D=phone" instead of "/search?search=phone" so that when they press back on the browser, it takes them to the homepage "/"?

#### For Context

On my homepage, I have the following event listener

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const router = useRouter();
const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push(`/search?search=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`)
  };
```

On my search page.tsx, I have:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

const SearchPage = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const search = searchParams.get('search');

  return (
    <InstantSearch
      searchClient={searchClient}
      indexName={indexName}
      initialUiState={{
        [indexName]: {
          query: search,
        },
      }}
      future={{
        preserveSharedStateOnUnmount: true,
      }}
      routing={true}
    >
      <SearchComponent />
    </InstantSearch>
  );
};
```